# SonarQube and Salesforce

Tags: apex

We are working in order to measure everything around our apex code. Few months ago we implemented PMD with some apex rules and now we want to start to use also SonarQube but it seems that Apex is not supported by default.

If any of you knows any plugin or something like that to use within SonarQube please tell me. I can not find anything.

I know there is one app with the name CodeScan (https://www.codescan.io/) but this app is used out of SonarQube and we have to use the native Sonar application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that now SonarQube provides support for Apex by default since version 7.5

https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarApex

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend going with [Codacy.com](https://Codacy.com) instead of Sonar. It's a real cloud solution plugin in all available Open Source engines.

I might be biased (find out who I am) but I dislike Sonar because they sell PMD as their own product while they do not actively help to grow the underlying Open Source project. I also couldn't get Sonar Cloud to work on Apex.